# Calling a method with an instance of derived class of derived generic type

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

Okay, so I have classes

```
class B<T> : A<T>
class L : K
```

and a method

```
void Method(A<K> a) {...}
```

What I would like to do is this

```
var b = new B<L>();
Method(b); //error
```

But it is not possible to b to the correct type. Indeed it is not possible to make this cast

```
A<K> t = new A<L>(); //error
```

I would really like to **not** have to change the internals of Method. I have no problems making changes to B and/or L. Do I have any options for making some sort of workaround? I guess it should be possible for Method to execute all of its method calls etc. on b, since B derives from A and L derives from K?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Comment: Also take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997386.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using C# 4.0+, you need to declare the type parameter of A to be covariant:

```
public class A<out T> where T : K
{
}
```

This should allow you pass a variable of B to a parameter of A

Some more info:

[Understanding Covariant and Contravariant interfaces in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719954/understanding-covariant-and-contravariant-interfaces-in-c-sharp)

Obviously in OOP you can pass a derived type to the parameter declared as a base type (that's the whole point). Covariance allows the same thing - but for type parameters, which is what you need in this case.

Comment: Apart from the fact that I A needs to be an interface for this to work, this is the solution I am looking for. And I can just declare an interface above A that has an out. Thank you!