# Convert references to generic classes in C#

Tags: c#, generics, collections, type-conversion

I tried a generic class conversion in a more complicated context first only to find out its not possible. So just for demonstration purpose I wrote this sample which is about the most general formulation of my problem I can think of, leaving out anything unnecessary:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace testapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // problem
            Generic<Sub> subvar = new Generic<Sub>();
            Generic<Super> supervar;
            supervar = (Generic<Super>)subvar; // <--fails
            // reason for asking
            List<Generic<Super>> list = new List<Generic<Super>>();
            list.Add(supervar);
        }
    }

    class Super { }

    class Sub:Super { }

    class Generic<T> where T : Super { }
}
```

So in general: Since every "Sub" is a "Super" I thought that every "Generic of Sub" is a "Generic of Super". So I expected that assigning a reference to a `Generic<Sub>` to a variable of `Generic<Super>` would be no problem, even without the explicit typecast.

But .NET Framework tells me this conversion is forbidden, why?

So, why would I want to do this? Suppose I would like to build a Collection that only accepts "Generics of *anything*", how would I do this circumventing the conversion?

Comment: Just because `Sub` is a subtype of `Super` does *not* imply that `Generic<Sub>` is a subtype of `Generic<Super>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx you can use the out Generic Modifier to achiev your goals.

For this you would have to add a new Interface that looks like this:

```
interface IGeneric<out T> where T: Super{}
```

And then change your generic Class to:

```
class Generic<T> : IGeneric<T> where T : Super
```

And you Main would then be:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IGeneric<Sub> subvar = new Generic<Sub>();
    IGeneric<Super> supervar;
    supervar = subvar; // No cast required
    List<IGeneric<Super>> list = new List<IGeneric<Super>>();
    ist.Add(supervar);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now my only problem left is that I am undecided, which answer deserves the green check :). I will give it to this one since it is probably the most helpful one for a user who randomly stumbles upon this question. But I strongly recommend reading the other answer, too, in order to understand why the interface is necessary at all.

Comment: @wulf21, if it helps, I agree that this is a better choice for the "accepted" answer and have upvoted it :)

Comment: @wulf21 i'm glad i could help you :)

Answer (score 3):

You have stumbled into the wonderful world of generic variance. Generic classes are always type invariant; in other words `C<T1>` cannot be cast to `C<T2>` unless `T1` and `T2` are exactly the same type.

Interfaces can be declared contravariant and covariant with `in` and `out` respectively. This allows casting "upwards" and "downwards" respectively, but classes cannot.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2720046/7122 for a very good explanation of variance and why `List` is invariant.

Comment: Thanks for the quick hint to covariant and contravariant interfaces. I will add them into my project. If I can achieve what I am trying to do with them I will mark this as the answer.