# MEF 2, Generic Import with implementing class

Tags: c#, generics, mef

I am trying to leverage the benefits of Generics with and MEF solution, however I am struggling to get things to register.  (Am using MEF 2, .Net 4.51).

Here is a simplified version of my classes and interfaces that I would like to work:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string Speak();
}

public interface IAnimalCatcher<T> where T : IAnimal
{
    string WhatICatch();
    T AnimalCaught { get; set; }
}

[Export(typeof(IAnimal))]
public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string Speak()
    {
        return "Woof";
    }
}

//[Export(typeof(IAnimalCatcher<IAnimal>))]
//[Export(typeof(IAnimalCatcher<Dog>))]
public class DogCatcher: IAnimalCatcher<Dog>
{
    public string WhatICatch()
    {
        return "Dogs";
    }

    public Dog AnimalCaught { get; set; }
}
```

and the code which does the composition:

```
 public class Program
    {

        private CompositionContainer _container;

        [Import(typeof(IAnimal))]
        public IAnimal TheAnimal;


        [Import(typeof(IAnimalCatcher<>))]
        public IAnimalCatcher<IAnimal> TheAnimalCatcher;

         public Program()
        {
            var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

            catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly));

            _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
            this._container.ComposeParts(this);

        }

    }
```

I cannot get the Dog Class to export and import correctly.  I have tried several combination without success (Commented above the classes).

The error is as follows:

> System.ComponentModel.Composition.ChangeRejectedException was
>   unhandled   Message=The composition remains unchanged. The changes
>   were rejected because of the following error(s): The composition
>   produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below.
>   Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed
>   information.
>
> 1) No exports were found that match the constraint: 
>     ContractName    MEFGeneric.IAnimalCatcher(MEFGeneric.IAnimal)
>     RequiredTypeIdentity    MEFGeneric.IAnimalCatcher(MEFGeneric.IAnimal)
>
> Resulting in: Cannot set import 'MEFGeneric.Program.TheAnimalCatcher (ContractName="MEFGeneric.IAnimalCatcher(MEFGeneric.IAnimal)")' on
>   part 'MEFGeneric.Program'. Element:
>   MEFGeneric.Program.TheAnimalCatcher
>   (ContractName="MEFGeneric.IAnimalCatcher(MEFGeneric.IAnimal)") --> 
>   MEFGeneric.Program

Note that `IAnimalCatcher<IAnimal>` will register, but that doesn't let me limit the dog catcher to dogs.

Is there a way to address this through importing, or is my design flawed, and should I be implementing DogCatcher differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MEF is looking for a type that exports `IAnimalCatcher<IAnimal>`. You have `DogCatcher` that exports `IAnimalCatcher<Dog>` so that is not a suitable candidate. Changing the export of `DogCatcher` to `IAnimalCatcher<IAnimal>` is not a solution because **you cannot assign `IAnimalCatcher<Dog>` to `IAnimalCatcher<IAnimal>`**.

If you were able to make the assignment you could then assign `AnimalCaught` of `DogCatcher` to `Cat` by setting the value of the`IAnimalCatcher.AnimalCaught` property of type `IAnimal`. You do not want `DogCatcher` to catch a `Cat` so the compiler will not allow it.

The solution is to change the `DogCatcher` so it implements `IAnimalCatcher<IAnimal>` and not `IAnimalCatcher<Dog>`:

```
[Export(typeof(IAnimalCatcher<IAnimal>))]
public class DogCatcher: IAnimalCatcher<IAnimal>
{
    public string WhatICatch()
    {
        return "Dogs";
    }

    public IAnimal AnimalCaught { get; set; }
}
```

The unfortunate side effect of this is that you now allow anybody to modify the animal caught by `DogCatcher` to say a `Cat`.

But there is another option. If you can remove the setter from `AnimalCaught` you can make the `IAnimal` type parameter covariant (the `out` modifier):

```
public interface IAnimalCatcher<out T> where T : IAnimal
{
    string WhatICatch();
    T AnimalCaught { get; }
}
```

This makes the assignment of `IAnimalCatcher<Dog>` to `IAnimalCatcher<IAnimal>` legal:

```
[Export(typeof(IAnimalCatcher<IAnimal>))]
public class DogCatcher: IAnimalCatcher<Dog>
{
    public string WhatICatch()
    {
        return "Dogs";
    }

    public Dog AnimalCaught { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: That addresses my problem,and also have now spent quite a bit of time reading on Covariant and Contravariant interfaces.  (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719954/understanding-covariant-and-contravariant-interfaces-in-c-sharp) as a good example.