# No implicit reference conversion between derived interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, implicit-conversion, derived-class

## The goal

Constructing a concrete object implementing `ICoolbag` and only being able to store `ICoolBagGrocery` instead of any type of grocery with `IGrocery`.

### The problem

The implementation below results in the following error:

```
The type 'SolidDistribution.Core.Bag.CoolBag.ICoolBag' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' 
in the generic type or method 'IBagStorage<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from
 'SolidDistribution.Core.Bag.CoolBag.ICoolBag' to 'SolidDistribution.Core.Bag.IBag<SolidDistribution.Core.IGrocery>'.
```

#### Implementation

**Bag**

```
// A bag that can only hold coolbag groceries.
public interface ICoolBag : IBag<ICoolBagGrocery> { }

// a bag that can hold any type of grocery.
public interface IBag<T> : IGroceryStorage<T> where T : IGrocery { }
```

**Storage**

```
// A storage that can store any type of grocery.
public interface IGroceryStorage<T> : IStorage<T> where T : IGrocery { }

// A storage that can store any type of bag.
public interface IBagStorage<T> : IStorage<T> where T : IBag<IGrocery> { }

// Base storage interface.
public interface IStorage<T> { }
```

**Grocery**

```
// A grocery that can only be stored in a coolbag.
public interface ICoolBagGrocery : IGrocery { }

// Base grocery interface.
public interface IGrocery { }
```

**Box**

```
// A box with a bag that can only hold coolbag groceries.
public interface ICoolBox : IBoxWithBag<ICoolBag> { }

// Base box with bag storage interface.
public interface IBoxWithBag<T> : IBox, IBagStorage<T> where T : IBag<IGrocery> { }

// Base box interface.
public interface IBox { }
```

#### Note

Changing `ICoolbag` to use `IGrocery` instead of `ICoolBagGrocery` like so:
(`public interface ICoolBag : IBag<IGrocery> { }`) fixes the error, but at the same time enables the ability to put any type of grocery in a coolbag. Which is obviously not supposed to happen :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Covariant and Contravariant interfaces in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719954/understanding-covariant-and-contravariant-interfaces-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compilation error is because `T` is invariant in `IBag<T>`.

`ICoolBag` is-a `IBag<ICoolBagGrocery>`, but `IBag<ICoolBagGrocery>` is *not* a `IBag<IGrocery>`.

If you were to make `T` *covariant* in `IBag<T>` (using `out`), then `IBag<ICoolBagGrocery>` would be a `IBag<IGrocery>`:

```
public interface IBag<out T> : IGroceryStorage<T> where T : IGrocery { }
```

However, this would place restrictions on your `IBag<T>` interface: properties of type `T` would not allow `set`, and methods could only use `T` as the return type, not an argument type.

For example:

```
public interface IBag<out T> : IGroceryStorage<T> where T : IGrocery
{
    T SomeProperty { get; } // Allowed
    T AnotherProperty { get; set; } // Compilation error

    T SomeMethod(); // Allowed
    void AnotherMethod(T t); // Compilation error
}
```

Furthermore, the variance would rise through the inheritance hierarchy, meaning `T` would also need to be covariant in `IGroceryStorage<T>` and `IStrorage<T>` to make this valid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will look into this subject some more because it ain't landing completely yet.

Comment: Yes, it's not immediately obvious. One simple example of why variance matters: `List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Apple>(); fruits.Add(new Banana());`. Clearly this shouldn't be allowed, and is why the compiler enforces it.

Comment: Yeah I do understand that. Am now looking further into the `in` `out` keywords and how this triggers different variances :) Thanks

Comment: When I specify `T` to be covariant in `IBag<T>` (using `out`), then make `T` contravariant in `IGroceryStorage` and also make `T` contravariant in `IStorage` (using `in`) I get the following error: `Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'IGroceryStorage<T>'. 'T' is covariant.`

Comment: Apologies, that should have been _covariant_. Each interface needs the `out` modifier.

Comment: If I would now create an abstract base class BaseBag implementing IBag<IGrocery> which has a generic IEnumerable<IGrocery> property that could be replaced by a more derived type like IEnumerable<ICoolBagGrocery> in case of ICoolBag. How would one do so? @johnathan