# Using abstract class as a generic type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core

Is there any way to use an abstract class as a generic type? I've given a very simple example below to simulate what I need. I get an error that an implicit conversion cannot be made for variable genericBehavior.

```
public abstract class AnimalBase { } // Cannot edit
public class Dog : AnimalBase { }   // Cannot edit
public class Cat : AnimalBase { }   // Cannot edit

public interface IAnimalBehavior<T> where T : AnimalBase { }
public class CatBehavior : IAnimalBehavior<Cat> { }
public class DogBehavior : IAnimalBehavior<Dog> { }

public class Startup
{
    public Startup()
    {
        IAnimalBehavior<Cat> catBehavior = new CatBehavior();

        IAnimalBehavior<AnimalBase> genericBehavior = new CatBehavior(); // This doesn't work
    }
}
```

Ultimately, in my .NET Core Startup, I'd like to be able to have the following:

```
services.AddScoped<IAnimalBehavior<AnimalBase>, CatBehavior>();
```

or

```
services.AddScoped<IAnimalBehavior, CatBehavior>();
```

What's the best approach?

Comment: @Xerillio In fact, as it is written now, `IAnimalBehavior<T>` is invariant, not covariant. Making it covariant would solve the problem: `public interface IAnimalBehavior<out T> where T : AnimalBase { }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Covariant and Contravariant interfaces in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719954/understanding-covariant-and-contravariant-interfaces-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Since are using `IAnimalBehavior<AnimalBase>`, and not `IAnimalBehavior<Cat>`, then this structure works:

```
public interface IAnimalBehavior{ }
public class CatBehavior : IAnimalBehavior { }
public class DogBehavior : IAnimalBehavior { }
...

services.AddScoped<IAnimalBehavior, CatBehavior>();
```

---

Having `IAnimalBehavior<T>` makes sense if you differentiate on T:

```
public class CatBehavior : IAnimalBehavior<Cat> { }
public class DogBehavior : IAnimalBehavior<Dog> { }

...

services.AddScoped<IAnimalBehavior<Cat>, CatBehavior>();
services.AddScoped<IAnimalBehavior<Dog>, CatBehavior>();
```